# React route from another file is rendered on every path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, path, react-router, url-routing

I'm trying to separate routes into their own file, but they seem to be always rendered, even if I've added `exact` to the `path`.

Home route - `home.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import { HomePageView } from 'components'

const HomeRoute = () => (
  <Route exact path='/home'>
    <HomePageContainer />
  </Route>
)
export default HomeRoute;
```

HomePageView.js:

```
import React from 'react';

class HomePageView extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>Some text here</div>
    )
  }
}

export default HomePageView;
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import HomeRoute from 'routes/home'
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <HomeRoute />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The problem is that it renders the `HomePageView` component on any path and I don't understand why this happens because it works as expected if I replace `<HomeRoute />` from `index.js` with:

```
  <Route exact path='/home'>
    <HomePageContainer />
  </Route>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this myself, but isn't the problem that you are importing BrowserRouter as Route in your home.js?

The file would looks like this when rendered:

```js
  <BrowserRouter>
    <BrowserRouter>
       <HomePageContainer/>
    <BrowserRouter/>
  <BrowserRouter/>
```

You need to import route from react-router-rom like this `import { Route } from "react-router-dom";`

"as" in import is an alias, not what is imported.

Fixed home.js file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { HomePageView } from 'components'

const HomeRoute = () => (
  <Route exact path='/home'>
    <HomePageContainer />
  </Route>
)
export default HomeRoute;
```

Comment: Yes, that's one of your problems. I think there is more to fix. A `Switch` component around your routes is also required and this introduces another issue as mentioned in the following [post - component nesting inside a switch component](https://dev.to/tylerlwsmith/how-to-get-around-react-router-4-not-allowing-nested-components-inside-of-a-switch-2hl). [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-http-yj4ns) is a demo setup with working routing.